# C++ call twice cause access violation

Tags: c++, access-violation

the first try to call that->getValue() looks good, but just the line below (the head of while loop) give me the error "access violation" inside the getValue method.

```
if(first != 0){
  listElement *that = first;    

  cout << "add: " <<    that->getValue() << " | " << value  << endl; 

  while(that->getValue() < value) {..}
}
```

Do i edit the the value during the call anywhere? The get method consists just of "return value"....

Comment: not enough information: what is inside `getValue`? what is going on inside the `while` loop body?

Comment: Need all the code. P.s. if what you saying is true the `while` is endless

Comment: Any reason you aren't using smart pointers?

Comment: I reverted your question because your edits completely changed it. We don't need to see the corrected code. If you had edited in the original, flawed code that would have been fine. But as it was, your edit just made the comments and answers seem incongruous.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious explanation is that in this code

```
while(that->getValue() < value) {..}
```

inside the `{..}` you are doing `that = that->next;` and setting `that` to the null pointer.

You need to add a test for `that != NULL` in your `while` loop to protect against getting to the end of the list without finding an item that meets your search criterion.

```
while(that != NULL && that->getValue() < value)
```

It would have helped if you had included all the code because it seems that the key bit of code is in the `{..}` block!

Comment: Hey, can you lend me your crystal ball?

Comment: @Vlad In the code we see `listElement`, `first` and `while`, all the hallmarks of a linked list iteration.

Comment: ok, you are right i call next() inside the while loop. Which i solved through setting the "first" variables next pointer to 0. But i still don't understand why it cause the error in the head of the while loop, would it be a do loop, it's evidently to me. But in this case the while loops header should be solved before next is called